# django channels. subscribe channel of certain user in receive_json

Tags: django, django-channels

in JsonWebsocketConsumer

i using this code for subscribe socket of certain user **(which is not current socket)** for messages from new dialog

```
def receive_json()
    # ...
    async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(f'dialog-{dialog_id}', f'user-{dialog.answerer.id}')
    # ...
```

but it not works because, i can't just set channel_name like that:

```
def connect(self):
    self.channel_name = f'user-{self.scope["user"].id}'
```

can i somehow subscribe socket of other user to group, having user_id?

Answer (score 0):

to achieve custom channel_name i just add this to my consumer class

```
@property
    def channel_name(self):
        return f'user-{self.scope["user"].id}'

@channel_name.setter
    def channel_name(self, name):
        pass 
 # this setter is necessary so that an exception is not throwed when creating a channel
```

Comment: Could you explain this solution, so that I could implement it because I am facing the exact same problem. Thanks in advance